# Python modify instance attribute with instance method

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use an instance method to modify one of the instance's attribute like this:

```
from torch.optim import SGD
from typing import Dict

class ChangeRateSgd(SGD):
    def __init__(self, params, lr: float, lr_change_instructions: Dict):
        super().__init__(params, lr)
        self.lr_change_instructions = lr_change_instructions

    def change_update_rate(self, input_epoch):
        update_mapping = self.lr_change_instructions
        if input_epoch in update_mapping.keys():
            new_lr = self.lr_change_instructions[input_epoch]
            self.lr = new_lr
```

However, my IDE flags the line `self.lr = new_lr` as not being ideal coding practice, with the warning `Instance attribute lr defined outside __init__`. What is the best way to do what I am trying to do with this instance method?

Comment: `lr` should be defined in `__init__`, `self.lr = None` for example is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code , you need to define the lr in **init** method and access that any other methods.

```
from torch.optim import SGD
from typing import Dict

class ChangeRateSgd(SGD):
    def __init__(self, params, lr: float, lr_change_instructions: Dict):
        super().__init__(params, lr)
        self.lr =None
        self.lr_change_instructions = lr_change_instructions

    def change_update_rate(self, input_epoch):
        update_mapping = self.lr_change_instructions
        if input_epoch in update_mapping.keys():
            new_lr = self.lr_change_instructions[input_epoch]
            self.lr = new_lr
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't "need" to do it this way, but it's considered good style.